# Changing hostname without restart via cloud-init isn't working correctly

Tags: server, hostname, aws, cloud-init

I followed [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87665/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-a-restart) while writing my cloud-init script.

I've tested and I have this in one part of my boothook script:

```
echo "HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME" >> /etc/environment
echo "127.0.1.1 $HOSTNAME" >> /etc/hosts
echo "$HOSTNAME" > /etc/hostname
echo "$HOSTNAME" > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
hostnamectl set-hostname $HOSTNAME
```

When I login to my system for the first time:

```
$ echo $HOSTNAME
aaa.bbbb.domain.org

$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.1.1  aaa.bbbb.domain.org

$ cat /etc/environment
HOSTNAME=aaa.bbbb.domain.org
```

But for some reason I can't understand:

```
$ cat /etc/hostname
aaa

$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
aaa

$ hostname
aaa
```

Not sure why! Any clues?

Comment: If I run `hostnamectl set-hostname $HOSTNAME` manually the moment I log in, it works fine. I tried moving it to a user-script that runs later around rc.local and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I actually discovered after a lot of tinkering and researching that what I am seeing is the intended behavior, although it is different from what I am used to on CentOS/RHEL systems.

To summarize [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/331936/setting-the-hostname-fqdn-or-short-name) from [here](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch03.en.html#_the_hostname):

> *CentOS & RHEL deployment guide* 
>   *say the hostname should be the FQDN; Debian specifies* 
>   *the hostname should NOT be the FQDN.*
>
> *The kernel maintains the system hostname.*
>   *This file should contain only the system hostname,*
>   *not a fully qualified domain name.*

I'm fine with it this way (sure makes shell prompts shorter!) I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong.

Answer (score -2):

you must edit `/etc/hosts` and add hostname like this:

```
127.0.0.1    aaa.bbbb.domain.org aaa.bbbb
```

Comment: Why? OP already added an entry for their domain to point to the loopback interface to.