# Abnormal long prompt / change username & computer name

Tags: bash, username, prompt

I've just tested out Ubuntu 16.04, my first time with Linux.

Now I  installed it just to try, and found out that u like it!
However, since this was only a test, I didn't select username and computer name with care, which resulted in an abnormal long prompt:

```
Hjiyhjihyig000@ihoihjjjjj000-HP-550-Notebook-PC-RU544AA-AK0:/$
```

Anyway to change this (easily for a newbie) ?

Comment: Do you want to change the username or just the prompt?

Comment: Well, username and computer name, since I might need to write them sometimes in the terminal, it would be easier if they where easy to remember

Comment: And [How do I change the hostname without a restart?](http://askubuntu.com/q/87665/158442) - the computer name is called "hostname"

Comment: That might do the trick, I'll check it out, Thanks .