# How to change Ubuntu's terminal name

Tags: command-line

[image]

I've been reading about this topis [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22413/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-title) and tried the solution given to change the terminal name (refer to the picture on item number 1)

But none of them can change the terminal's name (item number 1).

```
user@linux:~$ gnome-terminal --title="SOME TITLE HERE"
user@linux:~$ 

user@linux:~$ PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007"'
user@linux:~$ 

user@linux:~$ echo -ne "\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007"
user@linux:~$
```

I know that item number 2 can be changed with `PS1`. But the title (item number 1) still didn't change even after I change the `PS1`

`user@linux:~$` is fine. I don't want to change this, I just want to rename the terminal's title on the top (item number 1)

Comment: I switched to another terminal because of no good way to set the terminal title. Using PS1 hacks it sometimes changes and sometimes doesn't. And usually PS1 shows where I am and the title should show the use of the terminal (what I want to do there). tl;dr bad decision to remove this functionality for quite some people. Look for alternatives if you rely on that feature like me.

Answer (score 3):

The feature `gnome-terminal --title` have been removed since Gnome v3
If you want to keep Gnome Terminal and change the Window title you will have to play with PS1, see below how to do it.

---

The Gnome 2 terminal has been forked as mate-terminal bundled in Ubuntu Mate. The `title` option is still available with this version
`sudo apt-get install mate-terminal`
[image]

---

With Gnome Terminal, a way to set the window title will be to play with PS1
You can add a function to your `.bashrc` file an call it to change the Window/Tab title

`nano ~/.bashrc`
Add the function

```
function set-title() {
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}
```

`source ~/.bashrc` to reload
`set-title Some new title` to change the Window/Tab title
[image]

Limitation: when a program changes the PS1, the title may change too (example: ssh to another host will reset the custom title)

Comment: Limitation: when a program changes the PS1, the title may change too (example: ssh to another host will reset the custom title)

Answer (score 2):

**`hostnamectl set-hostname` on 13.10+ desktop**

This is the best way if you have systemd (13.10 onwards) and if cloud-init is not active (see below):

```
hostnamectl set-hostname 'new-hostname'
```

It:

- does not require rebooting
- persists after reboots

More info at: https://askubuntu.com/a/516898/52975

**18.04 onwards: cloud-init**

18.04 Introduced [cloud-init](https://cloud-init.io/) which can control setting of the hostname so `hostnamectl` changes it won't stick after a reboot if cloud-init is installed. TODO: how to check if it is installed, is it installed by default on the desktop image or just server?

If you want `hostnamectl` changes to stay after a reboot, then you'll need to edit the [cloud-init config files](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), disable cloud-init's [hostname set/update module](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#update-hostname):

```
sudo sed -i 's/preserve_hostname: false/preserve_hostname: true/' /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
```

or disable cloud-init entirely:

```
sudo touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
```

See also: [How do I change the hostname without a restart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87665/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-a-restart/1047635#1047635)