# Customizing Ubuntu to look like mac

Tags: gnome, icons, mac, macosx, zsh

You should see my setup first.
I customized Gnome to look like mac

[image]

[image]

[image]

I even changed the name to macOS catalina but I don't know how to change the

```
Host> HP Slim Desktop 290-p0xxx
```

and that tiny ubuntu icon in Command prompt.I want to change that icon to "apple" icon.I am using "oh my zsh" with powerlevel10k.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: For Hostname, see [How do I change the hostname without a restart?](https://askubuntu.com/q/87665/816190)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the Ubuntu logo with Apple logo in Powerlevel10k prompt you need to add the following parameter to `~/.p10k.zsh`:

```
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_LINUX_UBUNTU_ICON='\uF179'
```

Comment: Not working, there's no such line in ~/.p10k.zsh

Comment: But, I found this one which can be used to change the icon but doesn't know the value to put in there.
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_OS_ICON_CONTENT_EXPANSION='${P9K_CONTENT}'

Comment: You need to *add* that line to `~/.p10k.zsh`. You shouldn't modify any existing lines.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!