# How should I change My Computer Name?

Tags: system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the computer name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9540/how-do-i-change-the-computer-name)

When I open my terminal it shows `gaurav@Lin:~$`
Out of this I want to change "Lin" which is current name of My computer, how I can do the same?

Comment: But that question is about 'Ubuntu Server' I am asking about 12.04!

Comment: @Gaurav, both process are same. Look at answers there. If those not sufficient then re-ask with more details. Otherwise, If that helps, please vote this Question to close. Thanks

Comment: I think it should work the same, though.