# How can I find out the ROOT password?

Tags: kubuntu, password, root

I installed Kubuntu 12.04 on this desktop last September and am the main user of the machine. I can perform most admin tasks such as installing new software with my password, which is also accepted using `sudo` in a terminal. Some tasks however ask for a root password - the most recent example being when I tried to re-install my HP printer. and my usual password does not work. I have looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) answer, but it doesn't seem to help as I know my own password. I need to know root's password!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/231849/how-do-i-avoid-su-ing-to-root

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I recover my root password?](http://askubuntu.com/q/9017/65926)

Comment: You should recover your root password. I don't know if there was command to know root password but you can change the password using  command `sudo passwd`

Comment: FYI: ***There is no root password in a default installation, because the root user account is disabled***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `sudo -i` in the console will drop you into "root" mode.

Comment: `sudo -i` is prefered due to environmental variables. See http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6188826&postcount=4

Comment: This is not useful because you also need a password to log as the "root".

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu by default does not have a root password set and relies *on your own password* entered via sudo for superuser/sysadmin purposes.

If you are adamant on setting a password for root then the following command will do it but it is NOT needed.

```
sudo passwd root
```

I would suggest just using `sudo` and then enter your own password.