# Total newbie wants to know - Ubuntu Tweak - changing the computer name

Tags: ubuntu-tweak

I have installed Ubuntu on an old PC to try and learn it and become familiar so I can switch away from Windows, although most probably not entirely.
I've put my machine on a network and would like to change its name. Someone in a reply to this same question by another forum member suggested the following:

> If you want a GUI assisted process install Ubuntu-Tweak. Among other
>   uses of this app is the ability to change computer name through tab
>   "Computer-Details" -> "Hostname"

I have downloaded and installed the latest version of Ubuntu-Tweak, however I do not see a tab named as suggested above. What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

The reason I started on a new question is that this reply was over 4 years old or thereabouts.

Thank you for your answers and consideration.

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu Tweak still supports that feature. You can however look at these questions for other ways to change the hostname: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9540/how-do-i-change-the-computer-name and http://askubuntu.com/questions/87665/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-a-restart

Comment: I have never used Ubuntu Tweak, so I cannot directly answer that question, but I can tell you the old-fashioned way to change your computer name: simply hit Ctrl+ALT+T and in the terminal that appears, enter the command `sudo hostname NEWCOMPUTERNAME`.

Answer (score 4):

Change hostname on this way

```
sudo gedit /etc/hostname
```

And change name

You should also edit /etc/hosts and change the line

```
127.0.1.1     your-old-hostname
```

Comment: It looks like, indeed, that feature is no longer supported in Ubuntu-Tweak or else I'm really dumb. I have seen the other answers on how to do it from a terminal prompt. I was just trying to make an easy transition from Windows to Ubuntu :-) Many thanks to all who answered!