# sudo unable to resolve host error message

Tags: sudo, hostname

I changed my hostname in:

```
/etc/hostname
```

And then also changed it with:

```
sudo hostname MATRIX
```

But I experienced a problem because (and I don't know if this is related or not) none of my applications would launch, not even Terminal, the processes would launch, but just stay in the `Sleeping` status. So I restarted the machine and all seemed well until I ran something with `sudo` and I got this error message:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host MATRIX
```

Why is this the case and how can I fix it so that `sudo` can resolve it?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

**Package Information:**

```
sudo:
  Installed: 1.8.9p5-1ubuntu5
  Candidate: 1.8.9p5-1ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 1.8.9p5-1ubuntu5 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to edit `/etc/hosts` and look for `127.0.1.1 your_hostname`

You can also have a look at:

[change the hostname without restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87665/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-a-restart)

[change the computer name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9540/how-do-i-change-the-computer-name)

Comment: and without sudo access, the only way to change /etc/hosts is either in recovery mode or from a live USB