# Unable to update hostname on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, hostname

I edited /etc/hosts file with the new host, then reboot my system but still I'm getting the old host name, how to solve it?
I'm using ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What about `/etc/hostname`? http://askubuntu.com/questions/9540/how-do-i-change-the-computer-name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system hostname goes in `/etc/hostname`.

`/etc/hosts` is for performing local name to IP address mapping.  It *may* contain your local hostname as a convenience, but it is not the location to *set* your local hostname.