# hostnamectl: command not found

Tags: apt, bash

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, when I try to run command `hostnamectl` I get error:

```
bash: hostnamectl: command not found
```

Which library shall I install to use `hostnamectl` ?

Comment: on my system it appears to be provided by `systemd`. I'm not sure whether it's available to you without that (in 14.04 which doesn't use `systemd`)

Comment: If you're just trying to change the hostname, have a look at the answer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9540/how-do-i-change-the-computer-name)

Comment: @SamirSabri You got `hostnamectl` in 14.04 by installing `systemd`?

Comment: no, but `sudo apt-get install systemd-services` installed it successfully

Comment: @SamirSabri If that is the case, shouldn't you accept the answer that said you to do so? The accepted answer suggested you to install `systemd` but you installed `systemd-services`!!

Comment: Yea, you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hostnamectl` is provided by [`systemd-services`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/systemd-services/filelist) package in Ubuntu 14.04. You need to install that package to get the command line utility

```
sudo apt-get install systemd-services
```

Comment: have you tried it? I got this error:`# sudo hostnamectl set-hostname new_host_name
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory`

Comment: @SamirSabri Yes. I used that in 16.04. The error seems like you have problem in dbus. You can ask a new question regarding this error.

Answer (score 2):

To find out which package a file is you can use apt- file:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
```

After using it it is as simple as :

```
ricardo@zeus:~$ apt-file search hostnamectl
cdist: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cdist/conf/type/__hostname/explorer/has_hostnamectl
systemd: /usr/bin/hostnamectl
systemd: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/hostnamectl
systemd: /usr/share/man/man1/hostnamectl.1.gz
systemd: /usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions/_hostnamectl
```

Once apt -file package tells you that the file is found , you just have to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install systemd
```

Comment: I tried that, I got similar result, but when I run `/usr/bin/hostnamectl` I get: `bash: /usr/bin/hostnamectl: No such file or directory`

Comment: if I try to run `ls /usr/bin` I can't see `hostnamectl `, however, `apt-file search hostnamectl` will show `systemd: /usr/bin/hostnamectl` can you please exaplain?

Comment: Once apt -file package tells you that the file is found , you just have to install it: sudo apt- get install systemd