# Showing different hostname on network

Tags: hostname

My hostname was smit-Aspire-5742 but now whenever I type `sudo fing`

it gives the following output

```
smit@smit-Aspire-5742:~$ sudo fing
[sudo] password for smit: 
16:00:07 > Discovery profile: Default discovery profile
16:00:07 > Discovery class:   data-link (data-link layer)
16:00:07 > Discovery on:      192.168.1.0/24

16:00:07 > Discovery round starting.
16:00:07 > Host is up:   192.168.1.2
     HW Address:   4C:0F:6E:3D:13:87 (Hon Hai Precision)
     Hostname:     Sanskruti-PC.Home

16:00:07 > Host is up:   192.168.1.1
     HW Address:   AC:F1:DF:E6:DB:5D
     Hostname:     D-Link.Home

16:00:07 > Host is up:   192.168.1.3
     HW Address:   C8:3A:35:CF:97:E9 (Tenda Technology)
     Hostname:     Shivai-Desktop.Home

16:00:08 > Discovery progress 25%
16:00:09 > Discovery progress 50%
^C16:00:09 > Discovery stopped
```

This is my laptop showing my hostname as Sanskruti-PC.Home.

```
   HW Address:   4C:0F:6E:3D:13:87 (Hon Hai Precision)
       Hostname:  Sanskruti-PC.Home
```

It was showing me correct hostname until my sister log in into the windows which duel booted with Ubuntu.I had tried everything on these links :-

[How do I change the hostname without a restart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87665/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-a-restart)

[How do I change the computer name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9540/how-do-i-change-the-computer-name)

I Also changed the computer name in windows from Sanskruti-PC.Home to smit-Aspire-5742 but nothing is happening.

here is output of my `hostname` command

```
smit-Aspire-5742
```

Is this a problem with hostname or [fing](https://www.fing.io/download-free-ip-scanner-for-desktop-linux-windows-and-osx/)?

output of the command `nslookup Sanskruti-PC.Home`

```
  smit@smit-Aspire-5742:~$ nslookup Sanskruti-PC.Home
  Server:       127.0.0.1
  Address:  127.0.0.1#53

  Non-authoritative answer:
  Name: Sanskruti-PC.Home
  Address: 192.168.1.2
```

And output command nslookup smit-Aspire-5742

```
  smit@smit-Aspire-5742:~$ nslookup smit-Aspire-5742
  Server:       127.0.0.1
  Address:  127.0.0.1#53

  Name: smit-Aspire-5742
  Address: 127.0.1.1
```

Comment: Sounds to me like an issue with your dns having cached that name. Try clearing it and retry your request.

Comment: @Ziazis    I Had tried to clean the dns cache like the way told here  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-debian-ubuntu-flush-clear-dns-cache/      but ,i am getting the same result.please can you tell me how can I clear that name??

Comment: What do you get if you type in, `nslookup smit-Aspire-5742` and `nslookup Sanskruti-PC.Home`, it could also be the cache of fing having saved your MAC address under the .home name.

Comment: @Ziazis I have posted the output of your command in question by editing it.Please take a look at it.

Comment: Look into your `/etc/hosts` and adjust the name there if it is set incorrectly.

Comment: @Ziazis thanks I have edited my file /etc/hosts.I just replace the ip address 127.0.1.1 with 192.168.1.2 and now I am getting correct hostname!!You should post it as answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Don't replace that address... add a new line for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61689/discussion-between-smit-patil-and-ziazis).

Comment: @Ziazis can you join in chat?? (If you are free)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added Line `192.168.1.2 smit-Aspire-5742` in My /etc/hosts