# Terminal Username

Tags: command-line, 18.04, username, device-name

So I am new to Linux and whenever I open up my terminal, my username is gansaikhan@gansaikhan: ; So my question is how can I change this terminal username to something like maybe gansaikhan@ubuntu: ...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Also pretty new with ubuntu but i actually did that earlier too.

1. Press the little down arrow on the right corner of the screen (near battery stage).
2. On the menu that appears, click on your name (gansaikhan) and than on "Account Settings"
3. Now you should press the "unlock" button on the top of the menu, enter your password in the prompt window.
4. tap on About tab. Here you can change your device name to "ubuntu".

Hope that helps and good luck to both of us (:

Answer (score 0):

The part after the `@` sign is your machine's name. You can change the machine's name by editing the `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` file. More information in this related topic: [How do I change the computer name?](https://askubuntu.com/q/9540/746347).

Comment: way more quicker then my answer... (: